# The type of column conflit with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005, I built a trigger that contains a SQL statement that unpivot's some data.  Somewhat similar to the following simple example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cdc1b/1/0.  Let's say that the table the trigger is built on is "table1" and it's set run after updates.

Within SSMS whenever I update "table1" everything works fine.  Unfortunately, whenever I update "table1" in a proprietary application (which I don't have the source code to), it fails with the message "The type of column conflit with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list".

After doing a bit of searching I added COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT to my cast's in the view without any luck.  It was a bit of a long shot because the collation all matched whenever I queried INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.

I then changed the casts from VARCHAR to CHAR and it worked without issue.  For obvious reasons, I'd rather use VARCHAR.  What is different between a SSMS and application connection?  I assume the application isn't using a connection property that SSMS uses.

PS: The database is a bit funky because it does not use NULLs and uses CHAR instead of VARCHAR.

Comment: It does work if you cast them all. See [Why does SQL Server require the datatype length to be the same when using UNPIVOT?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/54353/3690)

Comment: If you look at the SQL fiddle you'll see that both are cast as varchar(4000).  As I stated this works fine in SSMS, but when ran from a proprietary application it fails.  If I change all casts to CHAR(4000), it then works in the proprietary application.  Why is that?

Comment: You said the SQL fiddle was "somewhat similar". Not the same. Please post the actual table definitions and trigger code that reproduces this issue.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I can reproduce with the above SQL fiddle.  Its "somewhat similar" because I didn't want to confuse the issue with a bunch of unnecessary code.

Comment: Well I can't think of any connection setting that would be likely to affect this. As a workaround instead of using `unpivot` you could try `cross apply .... Union all` .Example syntax here http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35621/3690.